# Why linear-gradient does not work in Edge?

Tags: html, css, background-image, microsoft-edge

I made a gradation. This worked on Firefox and Chrome. But in Edge the gradient is invalid. I referred to tools and documentation such as Autoprefixer and MDN, but could not figure out the cause of this.

How can I work around this bug in Edge?

```css
.grad {
  --w: 3px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 6px, #000 6px calc(6px + var(--w)), transparent 9px) 0% 0% / 10% 10% repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="grad"></span>
```

---

- Edge: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363
- Firefox:  76.0
- Chrome: 81.0.4044.138

Comment: Edge uses the same rendering engine as Chrome. So if it works in chrome it works in Edge. If not you have an outdated version of edge. Please describe in which version of edge this should work (and why it's important that it should work in an outdated version)

Comment: @cloned You cannot know this. While the rendering engine is the same (when in nit-picking mode I would want to see evidence that they _really_ use the same code base), the issue seems to occur while parsing, way ahead of rendering. Empirically, the OP's demo does not work on Edge 44(18) which is the second but last version according to [this site](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/edge).

Comment: @collapsar I can know this because microsoft announced this. Edge version 44 is still the old, outdated version that uses microsofts rendering enge and not webkit. So unless it's a company controlled PC where you can't install anything I would really recommend to update Edge to the latest version.

Comment: @cloned It seems I had an incomplete idea of what the Chromium rendering engine is tasked with - as it kicks in with parsing you can indeed know and I stand corrected. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two adjacent positions in the `linear-gradient` spec are not understood by MS Edge. Therefore you should replace `linear-gradient(..., #000 6px calc(6px + var(--w)), ...)` with `linear-gradient(..., #000 6px, #000 calc(6px + var(--w)), ...)`.

Demo below, works fine on Edge 44 (18).

```css
span {
  --w: 3px;
}
.grad {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 6px, #000 6px, #000 calc(6px + var(--w)), transparent 9px) 0% 0% / 10% 10% repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="grad"></span>
```

Apparently MS Edge does not correctly parse or process the `color-stop-length` production of the [mini grammar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Formal_syntax) for linear gradient arguments. The respective [demo widget on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops) does not show either.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! BTW, is this a bug in Edge that the developers of Edge are aware of?

Comment: @zuNna I do not know, and honestly, I could not care less. Imho (and that is my very personal conviction only, of course, no solid evidence) MS has made clear that they do not want to fund this product in a significant way in the future, so I think it's dead meat for now. Afaik, there are feedback channels to the edge dev team though, if you have a MS account. A quick web search produced [this one](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-edge-insider/ct-p/MicrosoftEdgeInsider).

Answer (score -2):

Did you check if it has a padding. If you click to determine, so where you can see your padding and margin properties. Or you try to get a gradient from an Internet Tool.

OR the problem is because of the browser. Edge is not the best.

```css
.grad {
  --w: 3px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 6px, #000 6px calc(6px + var(--w)), transparent 9px) 0% 0% / 10% 10% repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="grad"></span>
```